# XSLT 1.0 pass to call-tempate a set of node names (analog of x in [a1, a2, a3])

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

It is an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717526/xslt-add-not-existing-nodes) question.

I have an XML fragment like this

```
<lines>
    <item><code>1.1</code><amt>1000.00</amt></item>
    <item><code>1.3.1</code><amt>2000.00</amt></item>
    <item><code>1.3.2</code><amt>3000.00</amt></item>
    <item><code>2.1</code><amt>4000.00</amt></item>
    ...
</lines>
```

And I want to add up some predefined set of codes.
Thanks to an advise, now I can do like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(item[code=1.1 or code=1.2 or 
code=1.3.1 or code=1.3.2]/amt)"/>
```

But I'd like to create a template and call it with easy readable params to list all needed codes. Something like:

```
... <xsl:with-param name="set" select="'1.1, 1.2'"/> ...
or
... <xsl:with-param name="set" select="'(1.1)|(1.2)'"/> ...
```

and then in the called template execute something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(item[code in $set]/amt)"/>
```

Is it possible in XSLT ?

P.S. I'm working with SAP XSLT processor which is quite restricted and it does not have matches() for example.

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass this parameter to the stylesheet at runtime?

Comment: It's trivial in XSLT 2.0, but you tagged the question 1.0. If you're using a version of the language that was superseded 8 years ago then you should really point this out in your question.

Comment: michael.hor257k: I'm not sure if I understood you well. But the stylesheet will be fixed. I know exactly which list of "codes" should be selected in a particular place. This is more for better code structure, better formatting centralization.

Comment: Michael Kay: yeap I'm using SAP XSLT implementation which is 1.0. They are quite slow with new technology implementations :) In fact they introduced XSLT 2.0 in the latest updates about a half a year ago. But this update is not available on most of my clients yet. Anyway I would appreciate for XLST 2.0 solution as well, for better understanding :) Although I'll not be able to use it.

Comment: "*This is more for better code structure, better formatting centralization.*" IMHO what you have is good and efficient code, and it's not going to get better by adding a redundant step to extract the values from a **string** (XSLT 1.0 has no *sequence*). If your values were dynamic, then there might be a point in keeping them **as XML** somewhere they can be updated if necessary. Otherwise, if you only want to make the list "*more readable*", consider commenting your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="set"
    select="'(1.1)(1.2)(2.1)'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <answer>
        <xsl:call-template name="sum-it">
            <xsl:with-param name="set" select="$set"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="items" select="lines/item"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </answer>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sum-it">
    <xsl:param name="set"/>
    <xsl:param name="items"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="sum(
        $items[contains($set,concat('(', code ,')'))]/amt)"/>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Once I looked at the XPath I had created for this, I realized that parentheses was probably not the best choice for delimiters.  My God, it looks like Lisp!

Comment: Hmm, looks logical but does not work :( Stops when I add concat (if I try to do simpler expression first).

Comment: I tested it with xsltproc before I posted it.  Everything I used is standard XPath 1.0.  What do you mean it "stops"?

Comment: Hi bjimba. Sorry couldn't answer for a time. I doublechecked - you're right - it works - it seems I did something wrong the first time. Sorry :) Thanks !